# Gitlab cannot merge reverted branch with another branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control, gitlab

i have a gitlab problem. Let's say i have branch A,B,C.
I once merge branch B to branch A and branch A to branch C. Then i do some commits in branch C and i just realized that i merged the wrong branch. Then, i looked at the commit history of branch C and try to revert each commit from the the last one to the one that i commit where merged branch C with branch A. Now, when i tried to merge branch B with branch C, it says that "cannot merge this branch. the Source branch is X Commits behind target branch" or something like that.

To note, that all the changes is not in local branch, but in the remote branch or the server branch.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are alone working on branch C, I would `reset --hard` it to a commit just before the merge of A (wrong branch) to C.

Then I would do the right merge, and remake the new commits I made before.

This is better done locally, after cloning the GitLab repository, consideirng the [menu associated to a commit in GitLab Web UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html) only allows for revert, not reset.

Once the local fix is done, you will need a `git push --force` in order to override remote C with your new local history.

Comment: Everything i did were on the gui, now, is it possible for me to clone the repo on a specific commit and then do git push --force on that commit? So that the branch is now resetted to a specific node?

Comment: @tns2307 you just clone, then reset to the specific commit, then force push.

Comment: And thus i won't lose the commit history until the point i reset from the branch right?

Comment: @tns2307 yes, you keep everything up to the commit you reset (the rest is still there in the reflog)

Comment: Thank you very much, i think this is the answer i need. If the problem resolved when i tried that on the server im working on tomorrow. I will close this. cheers, mate. Thanks.